# What is the Different between String(describing: Int) vs String(Int)?

Tags: swift

I need to convert an `Integer` value to `String`. I made a variable with an `Integer` value and then I have printed that using `print`. What is the different between the below approaches?

```
var word = "Count is "
var count = 100

print(word+String(describing: count)); // Count is 100

print(word+String(count)); // Count is 100
```

Comment: Does one handle different notations (scientific notation) while the other doesn't?

Answer (score 24):

Your question is actually unnecessary because if *all* you want to do here is print, you can just do it directly:

```
print("Count is", count) // Count is 100
```

That's because `print` takes a variadic parameter and inserts space as the default separator.

However, let's answer the question anyway.

---

### Answer

It's the difference between *coercion* and *representation*.

**Coercion**. Certain types can be changed into certain other types. You can change a Double to an Int and an Int to a Double. You can change an Int to a String and a String (maybe) to an Int. This is possible because the second type has an initializer whose parameter is the first type. This is something you would do *in your actual program*, like this:

```
let sum : Int = x + y
self.myLabel.text = "Your total is \(String(sum))"
```

**Representation**. For debugging purposes, all types can benefit from being representable as a string. Suppose you have a Person type. You can't change a Person to a String and vice versa — that makes no sense — but you would surely like to be able to `print` a Person to the console to see if you are getting the right results. This is possible because the Person type itself supplies a printable description. This is something you would do *for debugging purposes*:

```
let p = Person(first:"Matt", last:"Neuburg")
print("p is \(String(describing:p))")
```

---

### Comments

**Comment 1**. This distinction is fairly new in Swift. It used to be that `String(...)` was used to express both notions. But the powers that be realized that that was a confusing conflation of the two distinct mechanisms. So nowadays, an attempt to write `String(p)` will fail, whereas earlier it would have succeeded. String has no Person initializer, so `String(p)` is forbidden; you now have to say *explicitly* that you are *describing*, not *coercing*.

**Comment 2**. The need to print a description is so obviously common that you do not have to pass thru `String(describing:)` if all you want to do is log the object itself. You can write `print(p)`, because this is a *shorthand* for `print(String(describing:p))`. Similarly, string interpolation calls `String(describing:)` for you, so you can write `print("p is \(p)")`. And, as I said at the outset, `print` takes a variadic parameter and inserts space as the default separator, so you can write `print("p is", p)`.

Comment: Shorter: if you know Python, `String(...)` is `str(...)`, and `String(describing: ...)` is `repr(...)`.

Answer (score 13):

Reading the docs might help!

Here's an excerpt from [`String.init(describing:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/2427941-init)

> Use this initializer to convert an instance of any type to its
>   preferred representation as a String instance. The initializer creates
>   the string representation of `instance` in one of the following ways,
>   depending on its protocol conformance:
>
> - If instance conforms to the `TextOutputStreamable` protocol, the result is obtained by calling `instance.write(to: s)` on an empty string
>     s.
> - If instance conforms to the `CustomStringConvertible` protocol, the result is `instance.description`.
> - If instance conforms to the `CustomDebugStringConvertible` protocol, the result is `instance.debugDescription`.
> - An unspecified result is supplied automatically by the Swift standard library.

`Int` conforms to `CustomStringConvertible`, so `String(describing: someInt)` is the same as `someInt.description`.

Now let's look at `String(someInt)`, this calls this initializer:

```
public init<T>(_ value: T) where T : LosslessStringConvertible
```

`Int` also conforms to `LosslessStringConvertible`. In fact, `LosslessStringConvertible` inherits from `CustomStringConvertible`. `LosslessStringConvertible` specifies only one requirement - an initializer that takes a string.

The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/2431675-init) for `init<T>(_:)` says this:

> Creates an instance from the description of a given `LosslessStringConvertible` instance.

Even though `description` is not in a monospace font, I am quite sure (though not 100%) that this refers to the `description` property of `CustomStringConvertible`.

Assuming that `init<T>(_:)` indeed returns the `description`, `String(describing: someInt)` always returns the same value as `String(someInt)`.

Note that this does not hold true for all types. It only holds true for types that conforms to `LosslessStringConvertible` but not `TextOutputStreamable`. If you have a type that conforms to both, results can be different:

```
struct A: TextOutputStreamable, LosslessStringConvertible {
    init?(_ description: String) { }

    init() { }

    var description: String {
        return "foo"
    }

    func write<Target>(to target: inout Target) where Target : TextOutputStream {
        target.write("bar")
    }
}

String(describing: A()) // bar
String(A()) // foo
```