# Regarding assigning value of type Int to type String in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am parsing JSON data to `UITableView` in which it consists of one image and 5 labels in which one is of type `Int` and rest are of type `String`. I have parsed data for type `String` but when I add `Int` type to my model class and then write code for displaying cells in `cellForItemAt` method of `UITableViewDelegate`, it says cannot assign value of type Int to String.

Here is the screenshot of my app I have tried:

[image: running app screenshot]

In this, where it says `firstappear`, there I want to display year like `1970`.

**Modal Class:**

```
class Hero {
    var name:String?
    var team:String?
    var imageUrl:String?
    var realname:String?
    var firstappearance:Int?
    var publisher:String?

    init(name:String?, team:String?, imageUrl:String?, realname:String?, firstappearance:Int?, publisher:String?) {
        self.name = name
        self.team = team
        self.imageUrl = imageUrl
        self.realname = realname
        self.firstappearance = firstappearance
        self.publisher = publisher
    }
}
```

ViewController:

[image: my view controller file]

Also when i click the cell in table view i want to display all the contents to another view. I have tried didselectrowat method of table view, but not getting correctly

my source code for didselectroe method as below

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let heroesDetails:HeroesDetailsViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HeroesDetailsViewController") as! HeroesDetailsViewController

        heroesDetails.heroImage = heroesDetails.detailsImg
        heroesDetails.labelName = heroesDetails.detailsName
        heroesDetails.labelPublish = heroesDetails.detailsPublisher
        heroesDetails.labelAppear = heroesDetails.detailsAppear
        heroesDetails.labelTeam = heroesDetails.detailsTeam
        heroesDetails.labelRealName = heroesDetails.detailsRealName

        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(heroesDetails, animated: true)
    }
```

my another view controller file named as heroesdetailsviewcontroller swift file as below:

```
import UIKit

class HeroesDetailsViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var detailsImg: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var detailsName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var detailsRealName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var detailsTeam: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var detailsAppear: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var detailsPublisher: UILabel!

    var heroImage: UIImage!
    var labelName: String!
    var labelTeam: String!
    var labelAppear: String!
    var labelPublish: String!
    var labelRealName: String!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        detailsImg.image = heroImage
        detailsName.text = labelName
        detailsRealName.text = labelRealName
        detailsTeam.text = labelTeam
        detailsAppear.text = labelAppear
        detailsPublisher.text = labelPublish


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

}
```

code screenshot:

[image: didselectrowmethod]

Comment: don't/never put code as image, use edit option and past your code

Comment: `yourLbl.text` need string value and you are passing Int. so just remove Int from your code, will work

Comment: no i want integer value. i want to display it as 1970 etc etc..

Comment: @NishantNarola Your model has the key ** firstappearance** of type int whereas the data type of the key from the api [link](https://simplifiedcoding.net/demos/marvel/) is string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just looked at the API request -> https://simplifiedcoding.net/demos/marvel/

firstappearance is string, update your API model to string instead of int.

```
class Hero {
    var firstappearance:String?
}
```

It is understandable why you thought it is int, but check the type of the data not the value.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning `Int` type to your label which will never accept. So update your following line of code as follow:

```
cell.labelAppear.text = String(here.firstappearance ?? 0)
```

Comment: i tried but it is displaying 0 ..i want it to display as year which is in json data

Comment: So, there may be nil in `firstappearance`, please check you json.

Comment: Never use `String(describing:)` to show a value to a user. There are better ways to convert an `Int` to a `String`.

Comment: not getting it sir.dont know how to do it.iam stuck here

Answer (score 0):

Don't type caste again to Int.....

```
cell.labelAppear.text = String(hero.firstAppearance)
```

text attribute of UILabel requires string.

Comment: @NishantNarola so from the api you are getting a string value which makes the firstAppearance nil because it is expecting Int. so take care of that first and you will get desired output.

Comment: Never use `String(describing:)` to show a value to a user. There are better ways to convert an `Int` to a `String`.

Comment: thanks @rmaddy resaon -    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50774273/what-is-the-different-between-stringdescribing-int-vs-stringint