# Difference between String(int) and int.description in Swift?

Tags: swift, type-conversion

I understand the [difference between `String(describing: int)` and `String(int)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50774273/what-is-the-different-between-stringdescribing-int-vs-stringint).

However, I'm not sure what the difference is between `String(int)`, and [`int.description`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int/description) (or even `"\(int)"` for that matter).

Are these functions always going to return the same value?

```
let int: Int = 123
let string1 = String(int)
let string2 = int.description
assert(string1 == string2)
```

In this simple example, it shows they are the same, but I'm wondering if there are ever times they may be different, or if there are other reasons I may want to avoid one or the other.

I see `String(int)` being used a lot, but the other version is slightly easier to use on `Int?` values:

```
let optionalString = optionalInt?.description
```

Comment: If the object is indeed an integer, then passing it into an empty `String` initializer or using the convenience string getter called `description` are identical. If you command-click and jump to definition of `description` you will see that it's nothing more than a computed property that returns a string representation of self. The Swift language has all sorts of these convenient properties scattered around to make syntax a little cleaner. For example, `Date()` versus `Date.now`; they are identical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that you shouldn't use description method. Note that for integers the description result will probably never change but for other types there is no guarantee. For example `Data` used to have a different description a few years ago. Btw if you use `String(describing: optionalInt)` or string interpolation of optionalInt it will result in Optional("whatever")

Resuming usage of the description method is discouraged. Check [CustomStringConvertible description](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/customstringconvertible/description) If you want you can create a computed property you can extend `LosslessStringConvertible` and create a string property. It will allow you to use will all types that conform to it:

```
extension LosslessStringConvertible {
    var string: String { .init(self) }
}
```

Usage:

```
1.string     // "1"
2.5.string   // "2.5"
```